# Redirect a file with the hosts file?

Tags: windows, hosts

Do you guys know if there is any way to redirect a file (e.g. google.com/style.css) using the hosts file? What I'm trying to do is redirect a css file on a certain site to my own custom css file.

Answer (score 1):

The `hosts` file (Mind! A file doing exactly what its name suggests!) is a way to create a lookup between a hostname and an IP address. Whatever you **do** with that name/address is widley out of scope of the `hosts` file. The `hosts` file and its parser especially are completly unknowledgable of HTTP, so redirecting a **single file** on a **single protocol** is nothing `hosts` has any concept of.

Comment: Just to give them some kind of solution ... they could use Fiddler or another proxy to modify the HTTP responses.